# Python Bad Interpreter when executing

Tags: python

I have made a Python script for an in-depth project I'm working on.

But every time I execute it, I get this error:

```
root@vultr:~# ./login.py
-bash: ./login.py: /usr/bin/: bad interpreter: Permission denied

root@vultr:~# login.py
-bash: /bin/login.py: /usr/bin/: bad interpreter: Permission denied
```

My interpreter is set to `#!/usr/bin/python`.
My file is located inside `/bin/` to execute without being in the directory.
How do I fix this error?

Comment: What are the permissions on `/usr/bin/python` and your file?

Comment: can you `stat login.py` ?

Comment: Did you try searching for "bad interpreter" in SO? There's a bunch of results that may be related. *Hint: You misspelled interpreter* if you tried before.

Comment: I'm fairly certain the shebang line in your script contains an invalid character of some sort after the ``/usr/bin/`` part.